# Drop Random Pins Onto Dumby Map

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a little project that uses the mapquest API. While the map is being populated with all the pins that get pulled in, I want to make it where I have a "dummy map" that is shown as a static map and has pins that will fall onto it at random points. The pins will be nothing more than a series of styled div's. I can get them to move about the dummy map, but I cannot get them to each have a different position. How can I get the div's to each drop at a different positions? Also, what would be the best way to stagger the animations so they don't all fire at once? I'll put together a fiddle and include it below. Thanks for any input.

jsfiddle.net/45geyrzx/

Answer (score 0):

First enclose all those divs in another div, that you style this way:

```
<div id="holder" style="position:relative;">
```

This "holder" block will have a location on the overall web page that is relative to other stuff; if you add something above it, the block will move downward appropriately.

Then, for each of the divs that you have enclosed by that "holder", style them something like this:

```
<div id="div00" style="position:absolute; top='0px'; left='0px';">
```

This div item (note the 2-digit identifier allows for a total of 100 divs this way) will have an absolute position inside the "holder" div.  If the "holder" is moved due to some page-edit outside that block, everything inside the block, positioned absolutely, will be moved along with it, staying synchronized in terms of positions.

The key point is that those "top" and "left" values can be randomly assigned.  In your JavaScript code you can create an array, something like this:

```
var x,divarr=[]; //make sure divarr is global
for(x=0; x<100; x++) //do this inside an appropriate JavaScript function, just once
  divarr[x]=document.getElementById("div+((x<10)?"0"+x:x));
```

which lets you access each of the divs at any later time, so that you can change its "top" and "left" coordinates:

```
divarr[14].style.top=37+"px";
```

Here I've used 37 as an example, but you can assign any random integer you want.